# Integration Testing with Flyway

Tags: spring, flyway, integration-testing

I'm using [Flyway](https://flywaydb.org/) to handle the database migration. Everything is working fine: the default location of the migration files is:

```
main/resource/db/migration/V1...
```

I am running integration tests and my setup uses an separate database schema for integration, which I would like to manage with flyway as well.
The integration tests, though, are located in the `test` folder (not `main`). When the Flyway bean executes `migrate()`, it doesn't find the migration files because they are in the `main` folder. If I put the migration files in `test/resource/db/migration/V1...` it works.

I really don't want to have to copy these file into the `test` resource folder, so I don't have to maintain both. Is there a way to force Flyway to use the same migration files for the integration test as for the normal app?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I assume you're using Maven? For unit tests both `test/resources` and `main/resources` get loaded into the classpath. `test/resources` files usually take precedence, as they are placed higher up in the classpath - if I recall correctly. Regardless, I don't recommend you do this.

Instead I recommend you make an entirely different Flyway configuration for integration testing that is in a separate directory (ie `test/resources/integration/migration/`) and runs after the `main/resources/db/migration` default one.

Even then it might be easier to not use Flyway to setup your integration data fixtures and instead use some other database data loading tools like [DbUnit](http://dbunit.sourceforge.net) (I'm sure there are others).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I don't know why but yes you are right the integration test do "as well" pickup the file from the main/resource. I could swear it was not working. though... thanks for DbUnit I didn't know about it and I will probably start using to set the right content during tests (I'm just using flyway to create the tables design etc..)

Comment: I prefer the method that Adam put first. Here an example of how would do that in your properties file for Spring Boot:  flyway.locations=classpath:db/migration/postgres,classpath:db/migration/integration-setup

Answer (score 10):

Another hint:
For Database Unit Testing you can also use the Flyway Test Extension see https://github.com/flyway/flyway-test-extensions.

The extensions have also a addon for DbUnit integration for data loading so you got control for database setup in your test environment.

Adams answer is correct do **not** copy your real database setup scripts into `test/resources/db/migration/`.

For your integration test setup you can also do one or combination of following options:

1. Use for integration testing a maven profile and add in this setup a special `flyway-maven-plugin` or gradle setup that add the special folder `test/resources/integration/migration/` for script locations.
2. Use in test the identically folder `test/resources/db/migration/` and use special versions such as *V999.0.x__* or simular. In this case flyway will always fill all detected scripts in your database.
3. If you have spring 4.x project you also can use spring-test with SqlScriptsTestExecutionListner. Here you can use specific load function for test case.
4. use flyway-test-extensions

Tip for database integration tests:

- avoid database reset for single tests. Test will be faster and robust.
- each test data setup should be self contained and should not be disturbed by a other test run.
- If you need upgrade from existing delivered instance also add migration test for filled database in your test setup. => Test your migration scripts.

Comment: "Database Unit Testing" feels like soft diamond